# How to reach svg with style sheet:

Tags: url, firefox, svg, filter

In page svg and style sheet
  .elem{filter:url(#id)}

External svg and style sheet
  .elem{filter:url(svgs/filters.svg#id)}

In page svg and external style sheet
  .elem{filter:url(page.html#id)}

I need to reach in page svg with external style sheet (switching styles) BUT
full page is generated with script "window.open()" so it is "about:blank" = unknown url.

Any solution is welcome.

Comment: I suggest you create a jsfiddle to show your problem.

Comment: I am building a site to print Name cards and Calendars at http://users.atw.hu/nokiss with different themes (external stylesheets).
Could reach in page svg in Name cards ".element{filter:url(namecard.html#id)}".
But Calendar full page is generated with script. about:blank. Unknown url.
Themes could be edited by user with in page editable stylesheet.
At this time Firefox users need to edit filter part to take effect.

Comment: ps: Test Minicalendar mini4 theme